# Excel sheet column names had changed from A, B, C to 1, 2, 3

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007

Somehow column names in my Excel sheet got changed from `A, B, C, ...` to `1, 2, 3, ...`.

Could anyone please tell me how to change the column labels back to `A, B, C`?

Comment: Are there formulas? Sample Data, anything?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269866

Answer (score 1):

In excel 2007, in the Formulas tab of the Options menu, uncheck "R1C1 reference style."[image: Excel options menu screenshot]